# Reverse string list order

Tags: c, string

I would like to reverse the order in which strings are stored in an array, so that the last one becomes first in the new array. So far I am getting the data and storing in the first array but I'm stuck there. I just want to reverse the strings order, not the strings themselves.

Example input:

```
here is a sample
line two of test
```

output:

```
line two of test
here is a sample
```

So far i store the input in the first array:

```
// Accept user input until hit EOF.
while (( c = getc(stdin) ) != EOF) {
    if(input != NULL) {
        int c = EOF;
        int i = 0;

        // Accept user input until hit EOF.
        while (( c = getc(stdin) ) != EOF) {
            input[i++] = (char)c;
            input[i++] = (char)c;

            // If reached maximize size, realloc size.
            if (c == '\n') {
                input[i]='\0';
            }

            if (i == current_size) {
                current_size = i + len_max;
                input = realloc(input, current_size);
            }
        }

        input[i] = '\0';
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow - What have you tried?  You need to show some code.

Comment: What does the word "od" mean? Do you mean "order"?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ ? Or maybe...http://www.mit.edu/~puzzle/resources/haveyoutried.pdf

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code writing or tutorial service. Please edit your question to show a sample of your input and the desired output, and add the code you've written so far that isn't working as you'd like, and someone here can probably help you figure out how to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: input[i++] = (char)c;
            // If reached maximize size, realloc size.
     
     if (c == '\n')
       { input[i]='\0';}
           
      if (i == current_size) {
        current_size = i + len_max;
        input = realloc(input, current_size);
            }     
                  
        }
       input[i] = '\0';

    }

Comment: I tried editing your question to correct the formatting, but something isn't quite right. I hope I didn't mess it up.

Comment: @MarkM. Do you store all the strings in one single array?

Comment: yes , basically use the input array i have so far and store it in a new array in reverse; meaning last sentence becomes the first etc..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array of `char *` and that you know the length of the array:

Loop on the array, and swap the element at position `i` with the element at position `n - i - 1`, where `n` is the length of the array.

For `n` = 10, you get:

```
i = 0, n - i - 1 = 9
i = 1, n - i - 1 = 8
i = 2, n - i - 1 = 7
i = 3, n - i - 1 = 6
i = 4, n - i - 1 = 5
```

Remember to stop looping when you reach `n / 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store in a link list . it will be better and easy way to reverse the order.